# Equivalent predefined variables in azure from gitlab

Tags: azure-devops, gitlab, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, gitlab-ci.yml

I am migrating from `.gitlab-ci.yml` to `azure-pipelines.yml`

In one of the lines inside the `.gitlab-ci.yml`, there are variables
`$CI_PROJECT_ID`,`$CI_PIPELINE_ID`, `$CI_JOB_ID`.

I have figured out the equivalent for `$CI_PROJECT_ID`. In azure it is `$(System.TeamProjectId)`

However, need help in figuring out : `$CI_PIPELINE_ID` and  `$CI_JOB_ID`

Looking forward for some suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what these variables mean but consider this on Azure Pipelines:

- `$(System.DefinitionId)` - The ID of the build pipeline.
- `$(System.JobId)` - A unique identifier for a single attempt of a single job. The value is unique to the current pipeline.
- `$(Build.BuildId)` - The ID of the record for the completed build.

All predefined variables you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)